# Error: No Database Selected - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

HELP!!! I can't figure out why I am getting an error: no database selected. My code is below:

```
session_start();

$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'username';
$db_pass        = 'password!';

/* End config */

$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB     connection');

mysql_select_db("database", $link);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) 
VALUES ('$field1', '$field2')");

if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1) { 

    echo "success";
}
else 
{
    echo "Error: ". mysql_error() ."";
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions; they are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: Is ur database name is 'database'??

Comment: @Bhushya no, i changed it to that for privacy purposes when i posted it.

Comment: Then chk ur using proper database credentials or not.. even used credentials has required permission to the db

Comment: @Bhushya That worked! It was the database credentials. I just upgraded to cpanel and didn't realize you had to take that extra step. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible problems
1. Does "username" have access to "database" (PRIVILEGES)
2. Does "database" exist?

Side note - You should be using mysqli or PDO because mysql will be deprecated in upcoming releases